# Making gf match python imports

Tags: vim

I'd like the gf command to work with Python imports, but am having trouble with the `from foo.bar import baz` style of imports.

The basic problem is that I can't figure out how to make `include` or `includexpr` match the text between "from" and "import" and then add the text after "import". Vim seems to refuse to match past any whitespace, let alone allow backreferences to concat the two parts of the matched text.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's not only possible but the built-in Python ftplugin already handles all that for you:

- Find includes (irrelevant for `gf`):

  ```
  setlocal include=^\\s*\\(from\\\|import\\)
  ```
- Turn includes into paths (relevant for `gf`):

  ```
  setlocal includeexpr=substitute(substitute(substitute(
        \v:fname,
        \b:grandparent_match,b:grandparent_sub,''),
        \b:parent_match,b:parent_sub,''),
        \b:child_match,b:child_sub,'g')
  ```
- Add the correct extension (relevant for `gf`):

  ```
  setlocal suffixesadd=.py
  ```

Just make sure you have **either** of the following lines in your `vimrc`:

```
filetype plugin on
filetype plugin indent on
filetype indent plugin on
```

to enable the ftplugin mechanism.

Comment: Hm, my includeexpr is simply `substitute(v:fname,'\.','/','g')`. Is the one you mention in a later version of vim? I'm using 8.0. I think I saw yours in the vim src at head. I ended up writing my owner includeexpr function that does about the same, plus handling `__init__` files/dirs

Comment: Does that really work from "from a.b import c" statements? I think all that does is a/b, but nothing about c.

Comment: `gf` is "go to file", not "go to symbol". If you want to to go to `a/b`, then use `gf`, if you want to directly go to `c` in `a/b`, use `:help include-search`.